# Where is the solution of $yu_x+ xu_y = 0$ defined?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve $yu_x+ xu_y = 0$ with $u(x,0) = f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I get that the characteristic curves are $y^2 - x^2 = c$. There are two kind of such hyperbolas: those who intersect the $X$ and $Y$ axis. I have only boundary condition for the $X$ axis so the boundary condition tells be nothing about the hyperbolas that intersect the $Y$ axis.

Does it mean that the solution is not defined where $y^2 > x^2$?

If I add the condition $u(0,y) = g(y) \in C^1$, where will the solution be defined? I think that everywhere except for where $y^2 = x^2$ since at $(0,0)$ the characteristic curves are tangent to the boundary condition curve.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions $u$ will be constant on the hyperbolas
$$\phi_a:\quad t\mapsto (a\cosh t, a\sinh t),\qquad a\ne0,$$
and on the hyperbolas
$$\psi_a:\quad t\mapsto (a\sinh t, a\cosh t),\qquad a\ne0.$$
When $(x,y)\in\phi_a$ then $\phi_a$ will intersect the $x$-axis at the point $\bigl({\rm sgn}(x)\sqrt{x^2-y^2},0\bigr)$. It follows that
$$u(x,y)=f\bigl({\rm sgn}(x)\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\bigr)\qquad(|y|<|x|)\ .$$
If only $f$ is given the solution is not yet determined in points $(x,y)$ with $|y|>|x|$.

About the points $(x,y)$  on the common asymptotes of the $\phi_a$ and the $\psi_a$ we can say the following: The given PDE says that in such points $\nabla u$ is orthogonal to the asymptote, which means that the asymptotes themselves are level lines of $u$; whence $u(x,\pm x)=f(0)$ on account of continuity.